# Send responsive email with media queries in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, media-queries

We have a newsletter that uses media queries to display it in a responsive format for smaller screens.  It displays as it should in Outlook, but when the email is forwarded on, it appears that Outlook is removing the media query code. We are using Outlook to send the email since we have exchange lists that we need to include.  Does anyone know if there is a way around Outlook removing the media query code when forwarding, or another way to send an email with media queries through Outlook?

Comment: Sending mails with media queries. That's... brave :) Do you only support Outlook? What version of outlook?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Media queries are common in html email. They are not fully supported however in some web clients who strip the style tags (Gmail for example)

Comment: Do both rendering engines of outlook support them??

Comment: The email is a very basic design of a table set at a fixed width, so the media query simply alters the width if the device supports it.  Campaign Monitor has a list of devices that support media queries at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/#mobile-support. They also have a great article on building responsive email layouts as well.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Outlook uses it's industry famous Microsoft Word render engine to reinterpret html email. This means that when forwarding, your email is full of MS garbage and, in this case, removing some of the original wanted code.

I've had issues with some corporate exchange servers stripping media queries - I think caused by their security software. Try sending to a different domain.

Best way to see if it is stripping your media queries is to check your email code. Scroll to the bottom of your email and right click>view source just inside your Outlook viewing window.

If sending to a different domain doesn't work, I'm afraid you may be out of luck as there is no way to force Outlook to  preserve your original code.

Comment: You're right that in the source code it is removing the media queries.  Sounds like we will have to find a solution outside of Outlook to use to forward the email to these lists.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rounder Try ctrl+a copying the rendered html (not the code, but the result) out of a browser preview and paste that into Outlook. See if forwarding it that way makes a difference. It might preserve your code as outlook isn't reinterpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the newsletter via an Outlook email merge?

If you want better control, use a email newsletter service like [Aweber](https://www.aweber.com/landing.htm) or C[onstant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp).
Granted, you need your contacts to opt-in but this shouldn't be a big problem if they want your newsletter.

Comment: The original email is sent through a service called "Cision".  We then forward the email from Outlook so that we can send it to lists stored in Exchange.  But, that is where we can see that the source code is altered and the media queries are removed.  We do have a Constant Contact account and I have tried adding media queries to it, but from what I can tell CC automatically wraps all emails in a 600 pixel wide table, even if you add your own code and don't use their templates.  I haven't tried using an email merge, so I'll look into that and see if it offers a solution.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tyrant, I stand corrected on the CC issue.  I was able to apply a media query to all table tags and it is now working responsively.  Thanks for the suggestion as this may be an alternative solution since we can sync our Exchange lists to this account through the API.  Much appreciated.